# VSCode: Why did some colors of my tbrackets mess up ? (my theme did not change)

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I was casually coding sorting algorithms and I don't know what I did exactly (maybe clicked somewhere, did a key combination) but now some colors of my theme have changed. I'm still using the same theme as I was before (which is called `Monokai dark soda`) but brackets are all of a different color than before

Here is how it looks now :

[image: Now]

Before, the brackets used to be always white. Now you can see that most of them are yellow, and some of them are pink or blue.

I mean look at that last line, it's horrible!

Answer (score 9):

I just found the answer. I had accidentally turned on "Bracket pair colorization". (Edit: actually it had been turned on by recent update 1.67)

The solution to fix that is to go to File > Preferences > Settings > Text editor > Bracket pair colorization
and turn it off.

Comment: It seems that it was not you who accidentally turned this feature on. According to the release notes for the recent VS Code version 1.67: "Colored bracket pairs are now enabled by default."

Comment: Oh well, I was sure that it had actually happened while I was working on my stuff

Comment: bless you, this made me crazy...

Comment: The feature itself didn't bother me, but the super dark colours for the brackets in Typescript made them really hard to see. Turning it off I can actually see them again. Though turns out you can tune the colours, now I dig deeper.